# Can we use two where clauses at a time?

Tags: sql

```
select ename, sal 
from emp 
where sal between 1500 and 3000 
where job = 'manager' and deptno = 30;
```

I am getting an error like "sql command not properly ended"

Comment: Change the last WHERE to AND

Comment: still am getting same error.

Comment: Can you use [edit] and ADD the changed SQL?    (Please, ADD not CHANGE )

Answer (score 5):

You could write:

```
select ename,sal from emp 
where job='manager' and deptno=30 and sal between 1500 and 3000;
```